# How to merge two dataframes with hierarchical levels

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm trying to merge two dataframes with hierarchical levels having the same level 0, but **a different level 1**. The merge function seems the best to use because works like SQL, but I could be wrong. Anyway, as follows a view for both dataframes.

df1:

```
   201001       | 201002      |  201003
   col1   col2  | col1   col2 |  col1   col2
A  123    456   | 123    456  |  ...    ...
B  789    123   | 789    123  |  ...    ...
C  456    789   | 456    789  |  ...    ...
```

df2:

```
   201001             |  201002             |  201003
   col3   col4   col5 |  col3   col4   col5 |  col3   col4   col5
A  123    456    123  |  456    123    456  |  456    456    789
B  789    123    789  |  123    789    789  |  123    456    123
C  456    789    456  |  789    123    456  |  456    789    789
```

As I said, the level 0 is the same, the index at row level is the same, the only difference is the level 1. The result I would like is the following:

```
   201001                           |  201002      
   col1   col2   col3   col4   col5 |  col1   col2   col3   col4   col5
A  123    456    123    456    123  |  123    456    456    123    456
B  789    123    789    123    789  |  789    123    123    789    789
C  456    789    456    789    456  |  456    789    789    123    456
```

The keys to merge should then be the level 0 and the row index, while the columns on level 1 should be appended. I tried with pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True) and other combinations of parameters, but the only result is that the dataframes are just appended on axis=1.
Any idea on how I can get the right result?

Answer (score 0):

So far no answer, then I found a workaround: first I have joined the 2 dataframes with:

```
df_joined = df1.join(df2, how='inner')
```

This way I have a new dataframe with the common indexes, but this is not what I want as the 2 original dataframes are just appended on axis=1. Then I have extracted the values at level(0) starting from level(0) == '201001' creating a new dataframe and looping through the values at level(0) I have concatenated each block to the first one:

```
for q in list_of_level_zero[1:]:
    df_to_concat = df_joined.iloc[:, df_joined.columns.get_level_values(0) == '%s' % q]
    # concatenate the previous dataframe to the one with level(0) == '201001'
    # keep looping
```

The result is exactly what I need. I don't know if there is a more pythonic way, but at the moment this is the best solution.